# onClick event handler not firing when updating state directly - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm new to ReactJS. I have the following code, in which I try to update UI by updating `state` using an `onClick` event handler. However, the `onClick` is not firing and it's not even showing on the final HTML. I can see the button but the button is not bound to the event handler. My code is:

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
         data: []
      }
      this.setStateHandler = this.setStateHandler.bind(this);
   }
   setStateHandler() {
      var item = "setState...";
      var myArray = this.state.data;
      myArray.push(item)
      this.setState({data: myArray})
   }
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <button onClick = {this.setStateHandler}>SET STATE</button>
            <h4>State Array: {this.state.data}</h4>
         </div>
      );
   }
}

export default App;
```

My final HTML rendered on the browser is:

```
<html lang="en"><head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>React App</title>
   <style type="text/css"></style></head>

   <body>
      <div id="app">
        <div>
          <button>SET STATE</button><h4>State Array: </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
 <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

When I change `var myArray = this.state.data;` to `var myArray = this.state.data.slice();` it works as intended.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't like that space between `onClick` and `{this.setStateHandler}`...

Comment: I actually do see the event firing in webpackbin here, although I did change myArray to a copy of your state. Look at this webpack bin: https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KvMFcZ-2YzBatESvams

Comment: Yeah, once I do `var myArray = this.state.data.slice();` it works... Can someone explain that?

Comment: Even without .slice(), it would work. It's just a good practice to not directly push to your state or change/mutate it.

Comment: Just as a side note, you should avoid using `.bind(this)` as it is considered bad practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't see `onClick` handler in your HTML, that's how React works.

**Working code:**

```
class App extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         data: []
      }
      this.setStateHandler = this.setStateHandler.bind(this);
   }

   setStateHandler() {
      var item = "setState...";
      this.setState(prevState => ({ data: [...prevState.data, item]}));
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <button onClick = {this.setStateHandler}>SET STATE</button>
            <h4>State Array: {this.state.data}</h4>
         </div>
      );
   }
}

export default App
```

The problem in your example is within `setStateHandler` definition. You are modifying state directly which is [not a correct way to update state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly).

```
   setStateHandler() {
      var item = "setState...";
      this.setState(prevState => ({ data: [...prevState.data, item]}));
   }
```

In my example I use function as an argument to `setState` ([read when to use function as argument](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)) which will pass me a copy of component state. Then I use destructuring assignment (...prevState) to create new array with a `item` element. At last I return object to be merged into state.

Note that I used destructuring assignment for convenience and brevity. You can accomplish the same by just cloning the array:

```
   setStateHandler() {
      var item = "setState...";
      this.setState(prevState => {
        const newArray = prevState.data.slice();
        newArray.push(item);
        return { data: newArray };
      });
   }
```

Beside that you should also pass [`props` to base constructor](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class).
But that wasn't the issue in this case.

Comment: @swdon could you try to replace you component with what I've included in edit? let me know if this still doesnt work.

Comment: Yes, this works, could you explain the code a bit? What does the `...` before `prevState` mean? Please add some more details to the answer and will accept your answer.

Comment: @swdon I made the edit. I tried to make it clear as possible however it may sound more complicated than it really is.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `{String(this.state.data)}` or `{this.state.data.toString()}` instead.